# Should I have “shouldfail” unit test and “shouldpass” for all methods in TDD?

Tags: c#, xunit

Here is my class library code which I have C# and xUnit.

```
namespace XUnitSample.ClassLib
{
    public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
    {
        public void AddPersonToPeopleList(List<Person> people, Person person)
        {
            // TDD: 01 - Write a unit test which 'shouldfail'
            // If the 'shouldfail' unit test you wrote fail as expected, 
            // then your unit test is 'passed'.
            //people.Add(person);

            // TDD: 02 - Write a unit test which 'shouldpass'.
            // If the 'shouldpass' unit test you wrote fail as expected, 
            // then your unit test is 'passed'.
            people.Add(person);
        }

    }
}
```

And for my xUnit, I have one test class with 2 unit tests method.

```
public class DataAccessTest
{
    [Fact] 
    // TDD: 01 - Write a unit test which "shouldfail"
    // If the "shouldfail" unit test you wrote fail as expected, 
    // then your unit test is "passed".
    public void AddPersonToPeopleList_ShouldFail()
    {
        // Arrange
        var newPerson = new Person() { Id = 1, FullName = "John" };
        var people = new List<Person>();

        // Act
        var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        dataAccess.AddPersonToPeopleList(people, newPerson);

        // Assert
        // If count is not 1, unit test is 'passed'
        Assert.True(people.Count != 1);

        // If people does not contain new person, unit test is 'passed'
        Assert.DoesNotContain<Person>(newPerson, people);

    }

    [Fact]
    //TDD: 02 - Write a unit test which 'shouldpass'.
    // If the 'shouldpass' unit test you wrote fail as expected, 
    // then your unit test is 'passed'.
    public void AddPersonToPeopleList_ShouldPass()
    {
        // Arrange
        var newPerson = new Person() { Id = 1, FullName = "John" };
        var people = new List<Person>();

        // Act
        var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        dataAccess.AddPersonToPeopleList(people, newPerson);

        // Assert
        // If count == 1, unit test is 'passed'
        Assert.True(people.Count == 1); 

        // If people contain new person, unit test is 'passed'
        Assert.Contains<Person>(newPerson, people);
    }
}
```

Is this what it means by applying TDD principles of writing a unit test which `shouldfail` first and then write unit test which `shouldpass`?

Comment: This looks strange. The explanation for "should pass" and "should fail" are letter-for-letter identical. That makes no sense.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The copy paste bandit has struck again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Should fail" and "should pass" refer to the same test at different points in time, it doesn't mean that you write two separate tests. The TDD process starts with writing a failing unit test (failing because you haven't implemented the expected behavior yet) and then writing the code to make it pass.

In your example, the expected behavior is described by `AddPersonToPeopleList_ShouldPass` and this is the only test you need. You should write this before implementing the `AddPersonToPeopleList` method (at this point, the test will fail) and then go add the implementation (`people.Add(person)`) after which the test should pass.

Comment: Not 100% sure this was meant to be the red green cycle. I write "should fail" tests that are meant to cause exceptions. They pass when they do. We call them the "rainy day" tests.

Comment: See also [the happy path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path)

Comment: Many test frameworks have [`shouldFail`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/test/GroovyAssert.html#shouldFail(groovy.lang.Closure)) or [`assert_fail_assertion`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/test-unit/2.3.1/Test%2FUnit%2FAssertions:assert_fail_assertion) / [`assert_raise`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/test-unit/2.3.1/Test%2FUnit%2FAssertions:assert_raise) or [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) for that use case.

Comment: Based on the sample code in the question, it did seem like the OP was confused about the red-green cycle. Both test cases have the same arrange and act steps, but opposite assertions. I would expect the "rainy day" tests you describe to have a different setup (such as invalid input).

Comment: Also the commented out code in the SUT (under TDD: 01) suggests that the OP was indeed trying to write a test case that "passed" before the code was written.